# What are the different connections of MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have a software(toad for mysql) to connect to my MySql database.
We have to provide some data('username','password' etc) to this Software to connect database.
There is a field known as  'connection type' and it has 6 options

```
TCP
SSL SSH
NAMED PIPE
MEMMORY
HTTP PROXY
HTTP TUNNEL
```

Anybody explain about connection type and this six options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two are in your list

- NAMED PIPE
- MEMMORY

Are localized to the machine. i.e. do not use the network and thus are very safe

- [Named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) or [memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

The others use a network

TCP - Simple connection protocol using IP. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

HTTP PROXY, HTTP TUNNEL - Uses the [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) protocol to get over the (sometimes) problems of firewalls and routers). Either get a computer on the firewal just to forward requests on or just encode the reequests on the HTTP protocol (web) so it can pass thru. Both use TCP below it.

[SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSL) - Just encrypts the communiction and uses TCP forthe communication with the encrypted data.

[SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is built upon SSL but does the authentication bit.

**TO OTHERS - I HAVE SIMPLIFIED IT A BIT BUT GAVE LINKS**